# Error with Redis Autoconfiguration using Spring Boot 1.3.3 and Spring XD 1.3.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-xd

I'm trying to create a custom Spring XD (v1.3.1) module as well as utilize some of the Spring Boot Starter projects but I am running into an error with Redis.

I have a very simple sample project available here: https://github.com/fgreg/redis-error-example that reproduces the error. I think it has to do with the version of Spring Boot I am using.

Basically, when I try to run the integration test; Spring XD fails to start with the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'redisTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/RedisAutoConfiguration$RedisConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory]: : Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration$RedisPooledConnectionConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration$AbstractRedisConfiguration.properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisProperties] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration$RedisPooledConnectionConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration$AbstractRedisConfiguration.properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisProperties] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:464)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:129)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:129)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.singlenode.SingleNodeApplication.run(SingleNodeApplication.java:83)
    at com.example.UpperCaseProcessorIntegrationTest.setUp(UpperCaseProcessorIntegrationTest.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration$RedisPooledConnectionConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration$AbstractRedisConfiguration.properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisProperties] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration$AbstractRedisConfiguration.properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisProperties] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisProperties] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 61 more
```

However, if I downgrade back to version

```
"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration:1.2.3.RELEASE"
```

in my `build.gradle`, everything works fine.

I was looking through the Spring Boot 1.3 [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.3-Release-Notes) and the only thing that jumped out at me was the new support for auto-configuration of caching (including Redis).

I assume that since Spring XD uses Redis for analytics, Spring Boot is finding those classes on the classpath and trying to configure Redis. How do I get it to stop that? Or alternatively, correctly load the redis configuration that is present in the `application.yaml` file inside `spring-xd-dirt-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar` which is on my classpath?

I've tried the following with no success:

- Adding `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = RedisAutoConfiguration.class)` to my `IntegrationConfiguration` class. I think it fails before even taking my configuration class into account.
- Excluding the `spring-boot-autoconfigure` module from my dependencies. This just causes all sorts of other failures.
- I could try using the `spring.autoconfigure.excludes` property, but I don't know where to put that where it will actually work. I can't pass it as an argument to `new SingleNodeApplication().run()` (it fails as an unknown option) and it doesn't get picked up when I place it in the `spring-module.properties` file. Furthermore, I don't want to have to set this as a startup argument when I eventually get around to deploying this custom module, I want the module to be self-contained.

---

**Edit:** Some additional info. For my real project, I want to use Spring Boot 1.3 because of the [added support for Cassandra](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.3-Release-Notes#cassandra-support).

Answer (score 0):

I took a harder look at my dependencies and I noticed:

```
compile - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration:1.3.3.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.3.3.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.3.3.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.2.5.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.2.5.RELEASE
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.2.5.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    |    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.2.5.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.2.5.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.2.5.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.2.5.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.2.5.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.2.5.RELEASE
|    |    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.2.5.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.3.3.RELEASE <-------
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.3.3.RELEASE (*)             |
                                                                                       |
                                                               notice the 1.3.3 here----
...


provided
\--- org.springframework.xd:spring-xd-dirt:1.3.1.RELEASE
     ...
     +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.2.3.RELEASE <-----------
     |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.2.3.RELEASE                     |
                                                                                      |
                                                                                      |
                                                                 and the 1.2.3 here----
```

And sure enough, I looked at the runtime class path and it included both version 1.2.3 and 1.3.3 of Spring Boot. So it appears that since the XD DiRT uses Spring boot v1.2.3, I can't/shouldn't use v1.3.3.

My solution seems to be, don't use Spring Boot.